Custom CameraPreview Flutter
How can I create custom CameraPreview with certain size and save taken photo with the same size? (Flutter)
If the camera widget size is 400x150, the image also should be 400x150.

add dependencies to your pubspec.yaml file
dependencies:
  camera: ^0.10.0+1
  path_provider: ^2.0.11

Initializing the camera:
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final cameras = await availableCameras();
  final firstCamera = cameras.first;

  runApp(MyApp(camera: firstCamera));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final CameraDescription camera;

  MyApp({required this.camera});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: TakePictureScreen(camera: camera),
    );

}
}
camera preview :
class TakePictureScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final CameraDescription camera;

  TakePictureScreen({required this.camera});

  @override
  _TakePictureScreenState createState() => _TakePictureScreenState();
}

class _TakePictureScreenState extends State<TakePictureScreen> {
  late CameraController _controller;
  late Future<void> _initializeControllerFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = CameraController(
      widget.camera,
      ResolutionPreset.high,
    );
    _initializeControllerFuture = _controller.initialize();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Take a picture')),
      body: FutureBuilder<void>(
        future: _initializeControllerFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return Center(
              child: Container(
                width: 400,
                height: 150,
                child: CameraPreview(_controller),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          try {
            await _initializeControllerFuture;
            final image = await _controller.takePicture();
            final croppedImage = await _cropImage(image.path);
            // Save or use the cropped image
          } catch (e) {
            print(e);
          }
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<File> _cropImage(String imagePath) async {
    final image = img.decodeImage(File(imagePath).readAsBytesSync())!;
    final cropped = img.copyCrop(image, 0, 0, 400, 150);
    final croppedFile = File(imagePath)..writeAsBytesSync(img.encodeJpg(cropped));
    return croppedFile;
  }
}

Crop image :
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;

Future<File> _cropImage(String imagePath) async {
  final image = img.decodeImage(File(imagePath).readAsBytesSync())!;
  final cropped = img.copyCrop(image, 0, 0, 400, 150);
  final croppedFile = File(imagePath)..writeAsBytesSync(img.encodeJpg(cropped));
  return croppedFile;
}

I hope this will resolve your problem,

_cropImage function crops the image from 0,0 coordinates. Camera might be located in the bottom right part. There might located other widgets on top.
Even I'm trying to get widget size and coordinates, it appears stretched.

I have added code for cropping the image check that and tell me know, it work as expected or not.
